# I want one button to switch between two functions based on time?

Tags: javascript

What i have is a simple website where you input a number and when you click a button it divdes it by 16 and the answer pops up. But what i want to do is divide it by either 16 or 11 based on the time the button is clicked like if its earlier than 10:00 then it would divded it by 11 and anything later it would divide by 16.

```
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (!hasSubmitted) {
      hasSubmitted = true
      result.classList.remove('hidden')
    }
    value.value = Number(input.value / 16)
})
```

how do i make both functions work on the same button. I have no idea what to try since im totally new to javascript.

Comment: Do you mean time of day, or do you mean the number of times the button has been clicked?

Comment: You don't need to call `Number()`, the `/` operator always returns a number.

Comment: sorry i just read throuh it and found it equally confusing, just fixed it.

Comment: Get the time of day, then use an `if` statement to set the amount to divide by.

Answer (score 1):

Get the time, then set the amount to divide by depending on the hour.

```
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (!hasSubmitted) {
      hasSubmitted = true
      result.classList.remove('hidden')
    }
    var hour = (new Date()).getHours();
    var divisor = hour < 10 ? 11 : 16;
    value.value = input.value / divisor;
})
```

Comment: its giving me an error: Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).getHour is not a function

Comment: Sorry, should be `getHours`